# StreamingOutput equivalent in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have created a web application in spring boot in which I want to use Spring MVC rest framework instead of jersey. I am trying to do something like this but it gives me error. I want a equivalent of StreamingOutput in Spring MVC.

Ex: This uses JAX-RS StreamingOutput

```
public static StreamingOutput buildErrorEntity(Object error)
{
    StreamingOutput stream = outputStream -> {
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(printStream, error);
    };
    return stream;
}
```

I want to replace SteamingOutput but it gives me an error saying "Cannot resolve constructor PrintStream()

```
public static OutputStream buildErrorEntity1(Object error) {

    OutputStream stream = outputStream -> {
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(printStream, error);
    };

    return stream;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `OutputStream stream = outputStream -> {` does and why do you think so?

Comment: It is like a anonymous inner class that writes error to OutputStream.

Answer (score 6):

They've added [StreamingResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html) in Spring 4.2.